# Mapping in informatica

Tags: job-scheduling, informatica-powercenter

I have a job in GECS scheduler which will trigger a informatica workflow, if the job is late for 10 min then we need to create a mapping such a way that it will fail the workflow and trigger a mail to outlook saying the workflow is failed

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a specific programming problem?

Comment: Hi jmsinusa, I need to create a mapping in informatica.I have a job in GECS scheduler which will trigger a informatica workflow, if the job is late for 10 min then we need to create a mapping such a way that it will fail the workflow and trigger a mail to outlook saying the workflow is failed.

Comment: Can we do it in informatica?

Comment: yes, it can be done.

Comment: Hi Samik, can you explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can branch off your main workflow line to a timer task which starts as soon as the workflow starts. Set the timer to wait for the specified number of minutes then route to an email task on condition that the last task of the workflow has not succeeded. One caveat to this approach is that the workflow will always run for no less than the timer task is set for even when the rest of it has completed early. For this reason it is pragmatic to replace the timer task with a command task to a script which checks every few seconds for the final task completion and exits when this is true or after the set time interval